# Segmentation fault при вызове ассемблер-функции

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер

В образовательных целях пишу программу, запускающую bash. В дальнейшем планируется запуск от root, но пока застрял на запуске assembler-функции из Си. Если собирать бинарник из ассемблер-кода, всё работает, но при запуске программы:

```
char shellcode[] ="\x48\x31\xd2\x52\x48\xb8\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x50\x48\x89\xe7\x52\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";
int main() {
    void (*f)() = (void (*)())shellcode;
    f();
}
```

Программа на ассемблере:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:

    xor rdx, rdx
    push rdx
    mov rax, 0x68732f2f6e69622f
    push rax
    mov rdi, rsp
    push rdx
    push rdi
    mov rsi, rsp
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 0x3b
    syscall
```

Компилирую так:

```
gcc -m64 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o exploit priv_escal.c
```

Segmentation fault выбрасывает на первой же строчке shellcode(). Пробовал на Ubuntu x64, Kali Linux x64 (подсистемы Windows). Ассемблер x64. Это какая-то защита ОС или ошибка кода?

```
    disass main
endbr64
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
sub    rsp,0x10
lea    rax,[rip+0x2ed4]        # 0x4010 <shellcode>
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
mov    eax,0x0
call   rdx
mov    eax,0x0
leave
ret
```

Comment: а что именно делать должен код? он похоже пытается запустить что то странное. И похоже параметры для execve как то странно передаются.

Comment: Шеллкод запускает /bin/sh. Собранный и отлинкованный ассемблер работает как надо. Segmentation fault возникает на строчке 0x4010 (первая у функции shellcode)

Comment: программа нерабочая, так как в С не разрешается преобразовывать указатель на объект в указатель на функцию, а попытка разыменовать такой преобразованный указатель является неопределенным поведением, так как он указывает на функцию, а на массив char.

Comment: @user7860670, а если создать функцию и на её адрес записать (с помощью memcpy) shellcode? Такое может сработать?

Comment: Конечно нет....

Comment: @user7860670 а как по-другому? В Си я просто не очень давно)

Comment: На чистом С - никак.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью memory-mapping.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xd2\x52\x48\xb8\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x50\x48\x89\xe7\x52\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";
int main() {
    int shell_size = strlen(shellcode);
    void *memory = mmap(NULL, shell_size, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    memcpy(memory, shellcode, shell_size);
    int (*run)() = memory;
    run();
}
```

Comment: Ну, если кто не понял, то вся фишка в `PROT_EXEC`

Comment: У меня с `mmap` - нет навыка, надо-бы повозиться. Но у вас медленный `strlen`. Попробуйте `sizeof(shellcode)`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Уточняю. `mmap` сделает свою работу вплоть до первого нулевого байта программы. То-есть это даже не в скорости дело. Ошибка : `strlen` - вычеркните из памяти.